# How to perform benchmark of block/stream ciphers?

Tags: block-cipher, stream-cipher, performance

I would like to perform some benchmarking of different block and stream ciphers for general data (lossless and lossy data) encryption and decryption (with focus on power consumption).

To get general idea, I guess it probably would be better to use existing tools than to implement everything myself, then I can implement certain ciphers myself to get better performance.

Are there any tools that I can use for this initial benchmarking? Which tool support wider range of ciphers (cryptsetup?)

I am going to be doing this from Linux. The only options that I can think of now are cryptsetup and TrueCrypt... but can I use disk encryption utilities to benchmark encryption and decryption of general data?

Comment: I'd start by looking at OpenSSL's benchmarking suite. It's pretty mature and comprehensive for the ciphers they implement.

Comment: [eBACs](http://bench.cr.yp.to/) is a popular benchmarking suite which includes stream ciphers. You should be able to include your own ciphers into it.

Comment: eBACS is more of a project, with SUPERCOP being the benchmark suite that actually does the work

Comment: I think I've recently seen [ecrypt.eu.org's SVN](http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/svn/viewcvs.cgi/ecrypt/trunk/?rev=216#dirlist) having some benchmarking code available as download (it's the source of the benchmarking code estream used to test all submitted stream-cipher projects).